# How to create and import assets?

Tags: import

I'm a total beginner and I've tried four different tutorials on creating grass, but none of them go into importing the grass into Unreal Engine.
The first couple of tries, I converted it, exported as a smooth fbx, and got several different error codes. (A new one each time I tweeked what I thought would work).

Finally, after two whole days, I was able to import my grass along with the color material that went along with it. I did get literally thousands of what I assume to be children files to go along with it. So I deleted all the unneeded imports to result in three files. My 3d mesh (I assume that's what it's called?), my green color material and my transparent material to hide the square underneath the grass.

However I cannot figure out how to get it to turn into a foliage material.

I'm doing a learn-as-you-go process. Started with the basics, creating a landscape in unreal. Gathering textures to create my terrain materials, got my landscape painted. Now I want to start adding grass, rocks, trees, etc.

It would be most helpful if I had a video to work off of. However I don't want a tutorial where you use their assets. I want to know how to make it with my own assets so I can have full customization as well as being able to trouble shoot on my own.

---

Extra notes:
I am able to load the grass into the scene as a 3D object, however the square doesnt stay transparent, I imagine thats just a setting in UE4 that shows hidden items but a better proccess to doing this wouldnt be so bad either.

My first attempts I created a hair particle system, added lighting, wind, turbulance. those I couldnt get to load into unreal at all.

My more recent attempts. I created blades of grass in Blender, grouped them and generated a hair particle system from that. First attempt just resulted in 40,000 files of a single blade of grass. (I have no idea how when none of my rendered numbers for parent or children are even that high). I changed all copies to real instances and when importing it yielded in fewer stray files ( meshes of single blades of grass), but it also gave me the 3 materials mentioned above.

This is only something I've been doing for about a week. But I think I could have a great game concept and I really want to give it a go. I understand that working on my own I could be at this for years, but despite the frustrations it's also been a lot of fun.

I really need help understanding how to build assests in Blender. Things like landscape materials, buildings and animations. I have a general idea about working in UE4 but blender is a little more difficult for me to grasp, especially in the relation to making sure a file has everything it needs to be imported properly to UE4.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! A little tip about markdown: to get a soft linebreak you need two spaces at the end of a line before hitting Enter, otherwise it will be ignored and end up in one big wall of text. There is a little box at the top of where you type that can help you with markdown and you can also "suggest an edit" on other people's posts to look at their markdown if you see something more complicated (no need to send the "edit" in such a case). If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!